# How to generate the image from Histogram Equalization?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to implement the Histogram Equalization by myself, I have successfully generate the histogram after processing the Histogram Equalization. However, for practicing, I did not use the built-in HE function. Finally, I drew the histogram graph by a list which size is 256, and this list looks like that:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 5, ....., 200]
```

The problem is how can I use this grey value list to generate the after-HE image? Or in other words, how can I use this grey value list to generate a object of image type just like what the cv2.imread() do?

The code of presenting Histogram Equalization is as below:

```
def cal_HE(hist):
# calculate the size of image
    height, width = image.shape
    img_size = height * width
    img_histogram = [0] * 256
    curr_prob = 0
    for i in range(0, len(hist)):
        curr_prob += float(hist[i] / img_size)
        img_histogram[i] = int(curr_prob * (len(hist) - 1) + 0.5)
    return img_histogram
```

The *hist* parameter in the above function is generated by the function:

```
def output_ori_hist(image):
    hist = cv2.calcHist([image], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
    return hist
```

Now that I have the Histogram, but how to generate the output image?

Comment: Did you search for the mathematics behind it?

Comment: Yes, I know how to calculate that, but I have no idea how to turn the histogram to the image

Comment: After the equalization you should know the mapping between input colors and output colors, afair. From where you moved the histograms to where.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, you have to *invert* the CDF, i.e. for a given pixel value (y), find the _index_ (x) of this value in the CDF. -- give us real input data, and show your code. please review [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Thank you Christoph, I have put my code here.

Comment: [mre] means it has to be runnable, as is, a *complete* program. in python, indentation isn't for aesthetics. it is syntax.

Comment: ok so that's a good start, but your `calc_HE` should be named `calc_CDF`. and then you need another function to invert that, as described. and finally you can use `cv.LUT` to apply the inverted function to your (grayscale) image. -- for fun, you can try applying your original CDF to your image. that should make it look even more out of whack.

Comment: Thanks, I applied the origin CDF to the picture and it seems fine? Why I need to invert that?

Comment: hm right, my mistake. I always get confused with these things. no inversion needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ambiguous. what I understood you want generate histogram and Histogram for Equalization and save it on your disk, Am I right?

for this purpose:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  
# reading the input image
img = cv2.imread('car.jpg')
  
# define colors to plot the histograms
colors = ('b','g','r')
  
# compute and plot the image histograms
for i,color in enumerate(colors):
    hist = cv2.calcHist([img],[i],None,[256],[0,256])
    plt.plot(hist,color = color)
plt.title('Image Histogram GFG')
plt.show()
```

[image]

for creating a Histograms Equalization:

```
# read a image using imread
img = cv2.imread('car.jpg', 0)
  
# creating a Histograms Equalization
# of a image using cv2.equalizeHist()
equ = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
  
# stacking images side-by-side
res = np.hstack((img, equ))
  
# show image input vs output
plt.imshow( res)
plt.show()
```

[image]

for saving the output you just need to use this:

```
plt.savefig(file_path, dpi=300)
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's not the point. I have edited the question to make it clear. May you please take a look?